# Setting Model.PageNumber in ajax call not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

Why can't I do this?

When my controller method gets hit, the pageNumber is not sent through.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(">>", "PersonList", new { nextPage = Model.PageNumber + 1 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updateContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

Here is my action method signature:

```
public ActionResult PersonList(string searchString, string searchOptions, string sort, string sortDirection, int? pageNumber)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any error message in your browser console?

Comment: No, the action method still got reached.  I posted an answer to my own question, I forgot to rename the route value in the ajax call after renaming the parameter name in the action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I renamed my parameter name in the Action method, but forgot to rename the route value name in the ajax call.

Changing my ajax call to the following fixed this.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(">>", "PersonList", new { pageNumber = Model.PageNumber + 1 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updateContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```